# wordpress admin panel loop on nginx

Tags: permalinks, htaccess, nginx

After updating my nginx conf file for wordpress permalinks, wordpress administrator page starts redirect loop. Why? And how can I solve this problem?

My nginx conf file:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name en.mig.tj ru.mig.tj;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/mig.access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/mig.error.log;

    root /var/www/mig;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    location / {
        index index.php index.html index.htm;
        try_files $uri $uri /index.php?args;
    }

    error_page 404 /404.html;
    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;

    location = /50x.html {
        root /var/www/mig;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;

        fastcgi_pass php5;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_NAME $fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_buffer_size 128k;
        fastcgi_buffers 256 16k;
        fastcgi_busy_buffers_size 256k;
        fastcgi_temp_file_write_size 256k;

        include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Found solution for my issue, by adding this line to my conf file:

`try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;`

Comment: "by adding this line" - Presumably you _changed_ the existing directive inside the `location / {}` container? You shouldn't have _added_ anything more to your config.